# How to change the original value of a variable after `declare` it with a new attribute

Tags: bash, variable

When adding an attribute to a variable with `declare`, the original value of the variable is  not changed accordingly. How can I actually change the value of the variable according to the attribute declared? Thanks.

```
$ unset var; var=HELLO; declare -l var; declare -p var;
declare -l var="HELLO"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var=$var
```

> [**When the variable is assigned a value**, all upper-case characters are converted to lower-case.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-declare)

```
unset var; var=HELLO; declare -l var=$var; declare -p var;
declare -l var="hello"
```